# Merging dotted pairs into a Huffman tree

Tags: merge, scheme, huffman-code

I have a procedure called make-leaf-set which creates leaf-nodes and another procedure that sorts the lowest first-high.

```
(define (make-leaf-set pairs)
   (if (null? pairs)
    '()
    (let ((pair (car pairs)))
      (adjoin-set (make-leaf (car pair)
                             (cdr pair))
                (make-leaf-set (cdr pairs))))))


(define (adjoin-set x set)
  (cond ((null? set) (list x))
    ((< (weight x) (weight (car set))) (cons x set))
    (else (cons (car set)
                (adjoin-set x (cdr set))))))


"Predefined dotted paires"
(define pairs '((a . 2) (b . 5) (c . 1) (d . 3) (e . 1) (f . 3)))
=> ((leaf e 1) (leaf c 1) (leaf a 2) (leaf f 3) (leaf d 3) (leaf b 5))
```

pairs works perfectly when used (make-leaf-set pairs). Everything is sorted. 
I also use another procedure which is called make-code-tree

```
(define (make-code-tree left right)
  (list left
        right
    (append (symbols left) (symbols right))
    (+ (weight left) (weight right))))

(define (symbols tree)
  (if (leaf? tree)
     (list (symbol-leaf tree))
     (caddr tree)))

(define (weight tree)
   (if (leaf? tree)
     (weight-leaf tree)
     (cadddr tree)))
```

- Goal is to create a procedure which takes a list of pairs and then create a huffman tree.

As a start I've comed up with this

```
(define (grow-huffman-tree list)
  (successive-merge (make-leaf-set list) '()))

 (define (successive-merge par tree)
   (if (null? par)
      tree
   (append (make-code-tree (car par) (cadr par)) tree)))
```

As it sits it merges the two first elements and gives `((leaf e 1) (leaf c 1) (e c) 2)`.
But I want it to merge all the leaves so it builds up like a Huffman-tree, and I can't manage to merge the other leaves into this tree. I've tried to call `(successive-merge (cdr par) tree)` will result in an error on element d 3...

Comment: I don't think you've properly absorbed the advice from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350954/get-pairs-out-of-a-huffman-tree/  ; where is your data definition for the class of data returned from `make-code-tree`?  (For that matter, where is your `leaf?` procedure defined?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you start with smaller initial examples, and work out what `grow-huffman-tree` (and perhaps `successive-merge`, depending on whether that really is an appropriate helper routine here) does for each of the smaller examples.

E.g., I am having a hard time believing that this line in `successive-merge`:

```
(append (make-code-tree (car par) (cadr par)) tree)
```

can possibly make any sense at all.  (But then again, without a data-definition for `tree` that includes how instances of the class should be interpreted, its hard to say what is nonsense versus what is "clever."

Keep in mind also that the word "Tree" in "Huffman Tree" is quite relevant.  You do not want to build up a `Listof X`; you instead want a *Treeof* X.  So if you are seeing data that is printing out like:

```
 ((obj 1 2) (obj 3 4) (obj 5 6) ... (obj 100 101))
```

that is *not* usually seen as an interesting tree; that more usually thought to be a list.  (Strictly speaking, it can be interpreted as a tree; just a very shallow tree with a very large branching factor.)

A more usual example of a tree structure would end up printing something like this:

```
 (node a 1 (node b 2 (leaf 17)
                     (node d (leaf 26)
                             (leaf 17)))
           (node c 6 (leaf 18)
                     (leaf 1)))
```